# Is the 'undefined array key g-recaptcha-response' error in the error_log spam?

Tags: recaptcha, spam-prevention, email-spam

I've a contact form on a website with v2 reCAPTCHA on it I think. Works perfectly, user fills in the form and it doesn't generate any problems. Also, Eric Jones has disappeared so it works well.
What I get now though is a pair of entries in the error_log about every 3 hours.

```
[13-Jan-2023 08:09:24 America/Boise] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "g-recaptcha-response" in /home1/fencinh0/public_html/fence-panels/contact-fence-panels-colchester.php on line 263
[13-Jan-2023 08:09:24 America/Boise] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "g-recaptcha-response" in /home1/fencinh0/public_html/fence-panels/contact-fence-panels-colchester.php on line 263
```

Line 263.

```
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
```

Is that the spam emails causing that now?